# Extract data over a period of seven days automatically by using a scheduling mechanism ( cron job )?

Tags: python, matlab

Extract product data like Product name, images, description, price etc from Amazon.In for Adidas Shoes. Extract data in CSV format and connect this with a dropbox folder so that the csv file extracted is automatically uploaded into dropbox.( Hint: dropbox api). Extract data over a period of seven days automatically by using a scheduling mechanism ( cron job ).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Return Output Argument from MATLAB Function**

> You can call any MATLAB function directly and return the results to
>   Python. For example, to determine if a number is prime, use the
>   engine to call the isprime function.

```
import matlab.engine
eng = matlab.engine.start_matlab()
tf = eng.isprime(37)
print(tf)

True
```

See more details from [Call MATLAB Functions from Python](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-functions-from-python.html?s_tid=gn_loc_drop).

Comment: what is the process to install matlab library??

Comment: @RAHULVR Have look at [Install MATLAB Engine API for Python](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html) and [Get Started with MATLAB Engine API for Python](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/get-started-with-matlab-engine-for-python.html).